# Changing properties on FB's User object

Tags: c#, .net, facebook, facebook-c#-sdk

Can I change properties on FB's User object? Can I change "work" and "education"? I need to add information to these collections. I have user_work_history permission all right.

I used CS-Canvas-AspNetWebForms-WithoutJsSdk as a basis. Server replies "true" (in the id variable) but nothing gets changed. "100002852727242" is id on my app's fake test user, Dorothy Ambhebgbgbdb Liman. Tried also post to "me" instead with same effect (= zilch).

Here's my code:

```
protected void btnPostToWall_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (CanvasAuthorizer.Authorize())
    {
        var fb = this.CurrentClient;

        var parameters = new 
        {
            work = new [] 
            {
                new
                {
                    employer = new
                    {
                        id = "20528438720",
                        name = "Microsoft"
                    },

                    location = new
                    {
                        id = "109738839051539",
                        name = "Redmond, Washington"
                    },

                    position = new
                    {
                        id = "131108890265554",
                        name = "SDE"
                    },

                    start_date = "1991-01"
                }
            }
        };

        try
        {
            dynamic id = fb.Post("100002852727242", parameters);
            lblPostMessageResult.Text = "Message posted successfully";
            txtMessage.Text = string.Empty;
        }
        catch (FacebookApiException ex)
        {
            lblPostMessageResult.Text = ex.Message;
        }
    }
}
```

Original sample code was posting something on the Dorothy's wall, no probs there. Maybe I can't post to "http://graph.facebook.com/me?"? Couldn't find anything useful anywhere. Any ideas?

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently, you cannot POST to /USER_ID, only to connections on the User object, e.g. /USER_ID/feed. Hence, you cannot change properties on the User object via a POST.